# Преимущества курсоров при работе с иерархической структурой

Tags: sql-server, курсор

На интервью был задан вопрос: **какую пользу несут курсоры при работе с иерархическими структурами?**

До этого надо сказать много с иерархиями работать не приходилось. Есть в проекте пару таблиц «родитель-потомок», но и они всего лишь двух-уровневые.

И теперь решил взяться за более детальное изучение **иерархий** и **курсоров**. Но как-бы я не искал и какие-бы большими не были данные, на форумах программеры пишут, что касательно структуры «родитель-потомок» все хорошо работает при помощи `рекурсии` - `обобщенные табличные выражения (CTE)`. И никакой необходимости к прибеганию курсоров нет необходимости.

Я детально еще не капнул тип данных `hierarchyid`, но там тоже по моему нет смысла искать преимуществ курсоров. При поверхностном изучении это типа, насколько я понял тут вообще свои статистические методы есть по работе с узлами.

Думал быть может какое-то преимущество обнаружу со стороны клиентского приложения, а не администратора баз данных. Но Google ничего не дал. А в той литературе, которая есть у меня про курсоры вообще не говорят или материал на одну страницу. Более менее развернуто об этом говорит [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191179.aspx) и [Интуит](http://www.intuit.ru/studies/courses/5/5/lecture/146), но опят таки – ничего про работу курсоров с иерархиями нет.

Я уверен, что это преимущество не касается **производительности**, тут что-то другое).

Есть у кого-то какие-то соображения по этому поводу?

Comment: курсоры - костыль, у них нет и не может быть никаких преимуществ :) (да, у меня на проекте активно используются иерархии, вложенности больше 2)

Comment: кстати, вы пробовали узнать правильный ответ у того, кто вас собеседовал?

Comment: _курсоры - костыль, у них нет и не может быть никаких преимуществ_ @PashaPash, я тоже так считаю и начинаю думать, быть может в этом и был какой-то подвох - быть может интервьювер ожидал, что я удивлюсь и должен сказать: "Нет никаких преимуществ".

Comment: _вы пробовали узнать правильный ответ у того, кто вас собеседовал?_  @PashaPash к сожалению нет.

Comment: Попробуйте связаться с ним и узнать. Вдруг ответит. Но скорее интервьювер сталкивался с какой-то очень специфической проблемой, которую другие решили CTE или оконными функциями. Или просто не знал о CTE. Или считает что целостность результата - не главное, а главное - держать локи как можно меньше (хотя это тоже решается уровнями изоляции). Кто его знает.

Comment: а теги **C#** и **orm** имеют какое-то отношение к предмету вопроса?

Comment: @Anatol, теги `C#` и `ORM` я указал по той причине, что мне кажется, что преимущества курсоров на стороне приложения. Т. к. в официальной документации говорится: [_Applications, especially interactive online applications, cannot always work effectively with the entire result set as a unit_](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191179.aspx), что приложение не совсем эффективно работает со множеством, а гораздо лучше с отдельно взятой записью. Хотя эта эффективность никак не раскрыта.

Comment: CTE хороши при работе с иерархией, hierarchyid - мне показались тормозными (юзал их в SQL Server 2012-2014). У курсора есть пара фишек - первое, это то, что внутри курсора можно запускать хранимые процедуры, второе - это то, что на основе текущей записи, можно поменять другие строки в той же таблице на которой использован курсор. Эти фишки ОЧЕНЬ редко, но все же бывают нужны.

Comment: _на основе текущей записи, можно поменять другие строки в той же таблице на которой использован курсор_. @gofr1, `на основе текущей записи` Курсор делаеться **только для выборке**, я правильно понял? И _на основе текущей записи_ означает, что если я **изменил значение столбца в выборке, то измениться его значение в исходной таблице**, так? Это по моему случай использования не статического курсора.

Comment: Да на выборке. Можно и так если использовать `UPDATE ... WHERE CURRENT OF ...`. Я неправильно привел пример... бывают случаи (с той же иерархией) когда одну и туже строку в выборке надо обнвоить несколько раз (по какой-то причине), курсор может это сделать в один прогон (с некоторыми извращениями), иначе это делают в цикле или несколькими апдейтами.

Comment: @gofr1 проблема только в том, что такие операции не гарантируют целостность. и их чаще всего можно переписать на обычные апдейты с оконными функциями. кроме каких-то совсем уж хитрых случаев.

Comment: @PashaPash, я получил ответ у интервьювера (см. мой ответ).

Comment: @Anatol, я получил ответ у интервьювера (см. мой ответ).

Comment: @gofr1, я получил ответ у интервьювера (см. мой ответ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне удалось получить ответ у интервьювера, о том в чем же все-таки преимущества курсоров в иерархических структурах?

Вот ответ-цитата (текст жирным выделил я):

> Курсоры очень дорогая конструкция, ресурсозатратная. И их нужно
> применять **осторожно**. Однако есть случаи, когда их применение
> оправдано. Эти случаи связаны при работе с иерархическими структурами
> данных в обычном реляционной SQL базе данных.
>
> https://www.opennet.ru/docs/RUS/hierarchical_data/
>
> Посмотрите указанную ссылку. Обратите внимание как происходит перемещение и
> удаление веток в деревьях, заданных различными способами.
>
> Посмотрите пожалуйста внимательно **часть 2**, там где используются
> **курсоры для изменения структуры дерева**.

Comment: Не стоило постить это как ответ, и тем более отмечать как принятый.  В комментариях к вопросу вам явно написали, что для работы с иерархическими данными есть более современные и удобные инструменты. Рекурсивные запросы/CTE появились еще в 2008-ом SQL Server, за три года до выхода статьи. Возможно, ваш интервьювер про CTE просто не знал. Попробую оформить в виде полноценного ответа, с примерами "из статьи" vs. "как надо".

Comment: кстати, если вы посмотрите внимательно - то в статье используются курсоры для работы с materialized path. а с того же 2008-го года в SQL Server появился hierarchyid, который на самом деле и есть стандартная  реализация materialized path без курсоров :)

Comment: @PashaPash _Попробую оформить в виде полноценного ответа, с примерами "из статьи" vs. "как надо"_. Я был бы благодарен.

Comment: Кстати, про hirarchyId он был в курсе - он далее в конце отметил это: _Что я еще тут ожидал (услышать от меня) - это упоминание hierarchyId, типа данных появившегося в SQL 2008. Применение `hierarchyId` позволяет существенно упростить алгоритмы для `materialized path`_. Ну собственно как ты (@PashaPash) и сказал:).